# Which file we shouldn't commit on GitHub from Android Studio

Tags: android, github, android-studio

I am working on a project using Android Studio, I am using `GitHub` and `SourceTree` also.
The problem is when I make change in my project and open `SourceTree` then I see some files on Unstaged Files list like:

- .idea/mics.xml
- .idea/modules.xml
- .idea/vcs.xml
- ProjectName.iml
- app/app.iml
- app/build.gradle
- setting.gradle

I don't know these files should be ignored or committed after changes in the code. Please suggest.

Here is the `.gitignore` file under app folder.

```
# Built application files
/*/build/

# Crashlytics configuations
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Gradle generated files
.gradle/

# Signing files
.signing/

# User-specific configurations
.idea/libraries/
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/.name
.idea/compiler.xml
.idea/copyright/profiles_settings.xml
.idea/encodings.xml
.idea/misc.xml
.idea/modules.xml
.idea/scopes/scope_settings.xml
.idea/vcs.xml
*.iml

# OS-specific files
.DS_Store
.DS_Store?
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
ehthumbs.db
Thumbs.db
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out links below:

[gitignore/JetBrains.gitignore at master · github/gitignore · GitHub](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore) - for Android Studio

[gitignore/Android.gitignore at master · github/gitignore · GitHub](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore) - for Android itself

Comment: I have used your first link but still I am getting two .iml files, and still don't know which should be ignored and why?

Comment: Check if that files are already commited. ```.gitignore``` don't ignore files already tracked. Please check [http://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/3451543](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/3451543)